# How to consume WCF REST service from WP7

Tags: wcf, rest, windows-phone-7

i'm about to begin a WP7 project. i currently have a WCF REST service deployed on my LIVE servers, and my Android and iPhone clients are happily consuming this. how do i get my WP7 to communicate with my REST service? The server side ***is*** working fine and well, and there is no issue there.

what i thought i would be able to do was simply add my client library (compiled in SL) with all the interfaces, datacontracts etc, create a ChannelFactory, ensure the web behavior was on in the client and yay! away we go. this doesn't seem to be the case however. certainly i can't use the interface created because of the WebGetAttribute reference :S

what is the reccomended way? i would prefer to consume my service in the same way as the other services do for consistency, so i don't want to make new (and more verbose communication) bindings and simply expose the same service over a different endpoint. similarly using WebClient / WebHttpRequest just seems a bit backward: certainly we don't have to parse the response for the other types of bindings available, why would we for this?

any suggestions? basically i want to write as little code as possible to connect the client and the server (ideally as much as normal WCF communication would take) and would prefer to communicate with a channel, since there'd be no parsing or deserializing the JSON response on my behalf.

surely this is possible? most people working on mobile applications have chosen a REST service to communicate with, seems a bit odd that microsoft's mobile solution wouldn't neatly integrate with its own server side solution! i really hope i'm just stupid and have missed something quite glaring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe at this point [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/) is your best option.

Comment: i did think about writing something that did this: i'm guessing it's a standard HTTP call to the desired URL, and then uses the DatacontractJSONSerializer to turn it into the Type parameter (which would be my datacontracts). think i might cheat and use this tho - thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

Another REST Client library: [Spring.Rest](http://springframework.net/index.html#spring-rest-1.0.0-released)